Error 500 al intentar instalar prestashop en servidor local
estoy intentando instalar PrestaShop 8.0.2 en un servidor local usando MAMP, pero durante el proceso de instalación recibo un error HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error). Aquí están los detalles:

MAMP versión: 7.1 (2720)
PHP versión: 8.2.20
PrestaShop versión: 8.0.2
Base de datos: MySQL


Lo que he realizado es lo siguiente:

Descargué PrestaShop y lo descomprimí en la carpeta de htdocs de MAMP.
Configuré MAMP para usar PHP 8.2 y MySQL según los requisitos de PrestaShop.
Inicié la instalación accediendo a http://localhost:8888/miprestashop/.
Durante el proceso de instalación, apareció el error HTTP 500.

[Wed Nov 20 20:34:04.573246 2024] [fastcgi:error] [pid 66430:tid 123145539309568] [client ::1:65402] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php.fcgi", referer: http://localhost:8888/localinstallation/install/index.php?restart=true

¿Qué más puedo revisar o configurar para solucionar este error y completar la instalación de PrestaShop? ¿Podría el problema estar relacionado con la versión de PHP 8.2?
Agradezco cualquier orientación.

Prestashop 8.0.2 no es compatible con PHP 8.2
Se recomienda el uso de PHP 8.1.
Link de la fuente: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/basics/installation/system-requirements/#php-compatibility-chart


Para cambiar la versión de PHP en MAMP de la 8.2 a la 8.1, sigue estos pasos:

Abre MAMP: Inicia la aplicación MAMP en tu Mac.
Accede a las Preferencias de MAMP: Haz clic en el botón MAMP en la
barra de menú y selecciona Preferencias.
Selecciona la pestaña PHP: En la ventana de preferencias, selecciona la pestaña PHP.
Selecciona la versión de PHP: En el menú desplegable de versiones de PHP, selecciona la versión 8.1.
Guarda los cambios: Haz clic en OK o Aplicar para guardar los
cambios.
Reinicia los servidores: Para aplicar los cambios, reinicia los
servidores Apache y MySQL de MAMP.


He intentado cambiar a una version anterior a la 8.2.20 desde el display de MAMP pero solo me sale esa y una superior, la 8.3.9. He estado ejecutando el siguiente comando:
Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/bin/php -v
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2024 17:28:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
Pero aun así me siguen apareciendo las dos versiones que mencioné anteriormente. Y el localhost:8888 ok y funcionando. Tengo que ver como cambiar a la otra versión.

Tienes que instalar la versión correspondiente entonces.
